# How to move /var/log to another drive?

Tags: mount, logs, fstab

I have a fully configured openSUSE on my SSD and it just occurred to me that it would be better to tell my system to write logs not on SSD, but to another drive to reduce the quantity of write operations. So how do I achieve that? Should I just create a partition for it and mount /var/log on it via `/etc/fstab` or use symlinks or something? What would be the best approach?

Comment: That would be the easiest approach if you can afford to dedicate a fs to it, yes.  Although you might consider moving the entire `/var` elsewhere, not just `/var/log`.  `/var` is supposed to hold frequently changing junk.

Comment: Ok but how better to do that?

Comment: Switch to single user mode, mount the new fs somewhere, and use `dump` and `restore` to copy the existing contents of `/var` to it.  Resist the temptation to use `rsync`, `tar`, `cpio`, or similar for that, `dump` and `restore` is what you want.  Than rename `/var` to something else, create a new `/var`, add a line to `fstab` to mount the new fs over `/var`, and reboot.  When you're sure it works delete the old `/var`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura why not  tar? Been doing it over the years with tar without any hitch.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Limitations on path length, and handling of hardlinks.

Answer (score 1):

Mounting another file system seems like a lot of work to me.  Is there something wrong with using a symlink to elsewhere?

As for moving the whole of /var off the SSD, if /var is "supposed to hold frequently changing junk", that would seem like an argument for keeping it on the SSD.

Comment: Yeah, after some thought on the subject I figured as much. If I don't use SSD to the full, what's the point of having it? So I didn't do anything. Still, this thread was educational.